# Let $\{X_t:t \geq 0\}$ be a stochastic process with independent increments and mean function $m_{X}(t)=E(X_t) < \infty$.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes

Let $\{X_t:t \geq 0\}$ be a stochastic process with independent increments and mean function $m_{X}(t)=E(X_t) < \infty$. Let $0<t_1<\dots<t_n<t_{n+1}$. Show that
$$
E\left[X_{t_{n+1}}|X_{t_{1}}, \dots,X_{t_{n}}\right] = X_{t_{n}}+m_X(t_{n+1})-m_X(t_{n})
$$

My attempt: I would like to use the fact that for every $t_1<\dots<t_n<t$, $X_t=X_{t_{1}}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_{i}})+(X_t-X_{t_{n}})$
which is a sum of independent random variable, but it's a vague idea, maybe someone can help solve it...

Answer (score 1):

$X_{t_{n+1}}=X_{t_{n+1}}-X_{t_{n}}+\cdots +(X_{t_2}-X_{t_1})+X_{t_1}$. The first term is independent of $\sigma (X_{t_{1}},X_{t_{2}},\cdots,X_{t_{n}})$ and all the terms except the first one are measurable w.r.t. $\sigma (X_{t_{1}},X_{t_{2}},\cdots,X_{t_{n}})$. So, $E[X_{t_{n+1}}|X_{t_{1}}, \dots,X_{t_{n}}]=E[X_{t_{n+1}}-X_{t_n}]+X_{t_{n}}-X_{t_{n-1}}+\cdots +(X_{t_2}-X_{t_1})+X_{t_1}$. After cancellations this gives $E[X_{t_{n+1}}|X_{t_{1}}, \dots,X_{t_{n}}]=E[X_{t_{n+1}}-X_{t_n}]+X_{t_n}$

Answer (score -2):

We have:

$$
E[X_{t_{n+1}}|X_{t_1}, \ldots, X_{t_n}] = E[X_{t_{n+1}}|X_{t_n}] \quad \text{(due to independence of increments)}
$$

$$
= E[X_{t_{n+1}} - m_X(t_n) + m_X(t_n) |X_{t_n}] \quad \text{(adding and subtracting } m_X(t_n)\text{)}$$

$$
= E[X_{t_{n+1}} - m_X(t_n)|X_{t_n}] + m_X(t_n) \quad \text{(linearity of conditional expectation)}
$$

$$
= E[X_{t_{n+1}} - m_X(t_n)] + m_X(t_n) \quad \text{(since } X_{t_{n+1}} - m_X(t_n) \text{ is independent of } X_{t_n}\text{)}.
$$

Now, we can focus on the first term:

$$
E[X_{t_{n+1}} - m_X(t_n)] = E[X_{t_{n+1}} - X_{t_n} + X_{t_n} - m_X(t_n)]
$$

$$
= E[(X_{t_{n+1}} - X_{t_n}) + (X_{t_n} - m_X(t_n))]
$$

$$
= E[(X_{t_{n+1}} - X_{t_n})] + E[X_{t_n} - m_X(t_n)]
$$

$$
= 0 + E[X_{t_n} - m_X(t_n)] \quad \text{(by the properties of independent increments)}.
$$

Finally, we have:

$$
E[X_{t_{n+1}}|X_{t_1}, \ldots, X_{t_n}] = E[X_{t_{n+1}} - m_X(t_n)] + m_X(t_n)
$$

$$
= E[X_{t_n} - m_X(t_n)] + m_X(t_n)
$$

$$
= (X_{t_n} - m_X(t_n)) + m_X(t_n)
$$

$$
= X_{t_n} + m_X(t_n) - m_X(t_n)
$$

$$
= X_{t_n} + m_X(t_{n+1}) - m_X(t_n) \quad \text{(since } m_X(t_{n+1}) \text{ is constant)}
$$

So, we have shown that:

$$
E[X_{t_{n+1}}|X_{t_1}, \ldots, X_{t_n}] = X_{t_n} + m_X(t_{n+1}) - m_X(t_n).
$$

This proves the desired result.